# ASK I want to use 2 FOREACH in 1 table body VIEW laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to use 2 FOREACH in 1 table body VIEW laravel

like this for the EXCEL.VIEW.BLADE code

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Booking Status</th>
        <th>CreatedAT</th>
        <th>New row</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($datas as $hasil)
    foreach($pp as $res)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $hasil->BookingStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ $hasil->DeliveryCharge }}</td>

            <td>{{ $res->BookingStatus }}</td>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and for the code in the controller like this

```
$data = TR_BookingHeader::where('LogisticId', $this->qty)->get();
    $pp = TR_BookingHeader::all();
    return view('Excel', [
        'datas' => $data, 'pp' => $pp
    ]);
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Please show the full error message. And btw., you second `foreach` is missing an `@` in front.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```html
<tbody>
    @foreach($datas as $hasil)
    @foreach($pp as $res)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $hasil->BookingStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ $hasil->DeliveryCharge }}</td>

            <td>{{ $res->BookingStatus }}</td>

        </tr>
    @endforeach
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

Another example

```html
[
  state
    college
    college

  state
    college
    college
    college

  ...
]

@foreach ($states as $state => $colleges)
    <h1 style="center">{{ $state }}</h1>

    <ul class="nospace clear">
        @foreach ($colleges as $college)
            <li class="one_quarter first">
                <h3 class="center">{{ $college->college }}</h3>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```